# Animated Traveling route in iMovie

Tags: macos, imovie

I like to make a movie from my holidays where I travelled a lot through a country. What I would like to include is an animated traveling route in the Indiana Jones style. That means, you see an old fashioned map with some points for cities on it and then a red line is starting to connect city 1 to your next destination. I would like to do this by a straight line when I travel by plane and an actual path (maybe from a GPS file) when I travel by train. I hope you guys understand what I want!

Is this somehow possible with iMovie? Or are there any suggestions on how to do this? The build in map solution from iMovie is not what I am searching for since I see no way to customize the map as well as the path - only straight lines are possible, no real paths!

Comment: Since you say iMovie - are you OK using the iOS or OS X to do the assembly of your movie?

Comment: Well with both but OS X has more capabilities, so I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this in iMovie but you could do it as a screen recording in Quicktime Player then import that into iMovie. Open up any paint application, open your map, select a large red paintbrush, start Quicktime Player recording then draw your route in.

Comment: This approach worked pretty well for me, grabbing a screenshot of a map and annotating in Preview. I needed to increase the Tracking Speed in trackpad to the fastest possible in order to draw the route without needing to stop and reposition my drawing finger.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do exactly what you want in iMovie, but you can get close. 
You can put in as many GPS Coordinates as you want to make the path somewhat granular, but you probably would not want to put in all.

See my [YouTube video](http://youtu.be/cphIJAHZ2J0) for how to add coordinates. It is simple to string together maps in iMovie to make a path by having Map2 use the ending point of Map 1 as the starting point of Map 2 etc.

The video is for adding coordinates in iMovie 11. The new iMovie is quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

There is some functionality included directly into iMovie for this. You can press <kbd>Cmd-5</kbd> to get a list of possible map clips which you can drag into your movie and configure as usual. The background is not as sophisticated as in the Indiana Jones movies though.

Comment: I don't like the build-in maps functionality. Only straight lines are possible. No ways for individual solutions. And I would love to include a GPS track... Other suggestions?

Comment: Please revise your question then to explain why the built-in mapping options are not enough for you and what you are looking for additionally.

Comment: I thought I made it clear (I want not straight lines only but paths). Added it to my question.